# What output is used in bash (with HTTPie)?

Tags: bash, httpie

I'm trying to analyze this command:

```
$ http :"/hello"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
<headers>

<body>
```

I'm trying to save the whole thing in a variable `VAR=$( ... )` but to no avail so far.

If I run

```
$ http :"/hello" 1>/dev/null
```

everything disappear, so I derive that everything is standard output.

But if I try to send this to a file or to my variable, I don't see the initial portion. So I thought this was `stderr`, so I did `2>&1` but this doesn't have any effect either.

How can I go about understanding this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `http`? It may be altering its output, based on whether its standard output is a terminal or not.

Comment: It's from this tool: https://httpie.io/

Comment: Did you try `VAR=$( http :"/hello" )`? `so I did 2>&1` Please post the exact code that you have tried! did you do `VAR=$(...) 2>&1` or `VAR=$(... 2>&1 )`? Please prefer showing what you did.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPie alters its output, depending on whether it is writing to the terminal or a regular file.

From [the manual](https://httpie.io/docs#redirected-output)

> **Redirected output**
>
> HTTPie uses a different set of defaults for redirected output than for
> terminal output. The differences being:
>
> Formatting and colors aren’t applied (unless `--pretty` is specified).
> Only the response body is printed (unless one of the output options is
> set). Also, binary data isn’t suppressed.
>
> [...]

There are specific command line options you can use to override the defaults.

Comment: I don't follow how this relates to solving my issue, could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using option "-v" and "-o" to capture both headers and body in a file, as in:

```
http -v -o output.file "google.com/bla"
```

As mentioned by @chepner in the comment, some tools detect if stdout is a file or not and change what they output.

Edit: to work easiest as you wanted (to stdout) you can use:

```
http -v -o /dev/stdout "google.com/bla"
```

Comment: Such a hackish way to do stuff! This tool is terrible. I will try to make it work with -v. Thanks!

Comment: If you ask a question about a specific tool, the assumption is that you decided to use it. You could use alternatives (wget, curl come to mind), maybe they are better suited for your needs.

Comment: I wish I could man... I wish I could... I'm stuck with this..